# How to manipulate all parameters of a shell script at once?

Tags: bash, parameter

While for a finite amount of parameters one can explicitly do something like

```
wrapped_function "${1#prefix}" "${2#prefix}" "${3#prefix}"  # etc.,
```

isn't there a simpler way to manipulate *all* parameters at once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure there is,

```
wrapped_function "${@#prefix}"
```

The `$@` represents the collection of *all* parameters `$1`, `$2`, ... (see [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#APPREF)) in individual quotes, i.e. basically

```
$@="\"$1\" \"$2\" \"$3\" ..."
```

however, bash applies variable manipulations individually on *each* parameter, i.e.

```
${@#prefix}="\"${1#prefix}\" \"${2#prefix}\" ..."
```

---

The `${VAR#prefix}` syntax means if `$VAR` starts with `prefix`, remove it, e.g.

```
TEST="/tmp/var/bin"; echo ${TEST#/tmp}  # yields "/var/bin"
```

Similarly, one can use `%` instead of `#` to remove a suffix.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain this a bit more with an example showing this works?

Comment: @slm Voilà, did I forget something?

Comment: Thanks Tobias, much nicer now!!! If you feel like it you might want to show the prefix, I'd bet most ppl won't grok what you mean by it. I'd put an example where you echo out the results of `${$#prefix}` just so it's crystal clear to other passerby's.

Comment: @slm True, that won't hurt either